# Rails 3 + Whenever Gem + Rake logging issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, whenever, engineyard

The app is running on Engine Yard. I need to log some data from inside the scripts ran by Whenever. Here's what it looks like:

schedule.rb:

```
every 1.minute do 
  rake 'my_tasks:task1 my_tasks:task2', :output => 'log/my_tasks.log'
end
```

`task1` runs the script that has the following lines in it (just for testing purposes):

```
... 

log('test')


...

def self.log(string)
  logfile = '/var/log/engineyard/apps/my_app/test_log.log'
  File.open(logfile, 'a') { |log| log.puts(string << "\n\n") }
end
```

The problem is that none of the logs (my_tasks.log, test_log.log) get created, no matter what I tried. When I run `bundle exec rake my_tasks:task1` from console it successfully creates the test_log.log file and logs the message. What could be wrong? Is it related to how Engine Yard works?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to how Engine Yard works. I am not familiar with Engine Yard itself, but it is of a similar service as Heroku, and I know that in oder to send something to logs in Heroku, you have to use the `stdout` or `stderr`.

[See here for more details about Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging), and see if the same works for Engine Yard *(keep in mind that this does not allow you to have separate log files, it simply puts the logged line in the same log file as other logged lines)*.